# Culling duplicate arrays from a list of ndarrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a *very* large list containing ndarrays. Each of these ndarrays contains 3 separate indices each corresponding to a 3d point in another data structure, and represents a triangular facet of a tetrahedra. About half of these ndarrays represent duplicate faces, but the points may not be in the same order. I want to cull any duplicate faces, and generate a mask indicating which faces were culled or an index list describing the unculled faces.

For instance one of these arrays might be array[1, 2, 3]. If another array further on in the list was array[3, 2, 1] then I need to cull the second one, but keep the first.

The problem I'm having is that my current method is painfully slow to compute culling of more than a million faces. Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
def cull_faces(all_face_nodes):
    list_of_sets = [set(v) for v in all_face_nodes]
    counter = 0
    idx_counter = 0
    idx_list = []
    while True:
        if counter == 0:
            counter += 1
            idx_list.append(idx_counter)
        elif counter > len(list_of_sets):
            break
        elif list_of_sets[counter] in list_of_sets[0:(counter-1)]:
            list_of_sets.pop(counter) 
        else:
            counter += 1
            idx_list.append(idx_counter)
        idx_counter +=1
    return idx_list
```

I've been trying to wrack my brain to come up with a more efficient algorithm that doesn't involve checking every node against the full list of nodes but I haven't come up with anything. One of the important problems is that I need to do this in a way that provides a result with the same order and formatting as the input, but with removed duplicate points.

Comment: What is in `all_face_nodes`? If it's a list of ndarrays you will get an unhashable type error from `set(v)`

Comment: I don't have that problem, why would I expect that? I did clarify in an edit that I was wrong about the data structure. It's a list of ndarrays, but the ndarrays just contain 3 integer indices.

Comment: @Nick nah, you won't, `set` accepts any iterable, a `numpy.ndarray` would work.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `a1 = np.array([[0,0,1], [1,0,0], [0,1,0]]); set(a1)` :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Nick OP is doing `set(a1[i])` not `set(a1)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't see any sub-indexing in the definition of `list_of_sets`; and it wouldn't make sense to do `set` on one node, as `[0,0,1]` would be reduced to `{0,1}` with a loss of information

Comment: @Nick **of course not, it's iterating directly over the list**, i.e. `[set(v) for v in all_face_nodes]` where `v` is an `numpy.ndarray` object of shape `(3,)`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga if that's the case, then it doesn't make sense to do set on one node, as [0,0,1] would be reduced to {0,1} with a loss of information

Comment: No need to shout...

Comment: you are right about that.

Comment: I was assuming `all_face_nodes` was a list of something like `np.array([[0,0,1], [1,0,0], [0,1,0]])`, otherwise the code can't work properly as all of those nodes become the same when converted to `set`. Hence my original comment

Comment: @Nick yeah, the description is pretty vague. The OP should *always provide a [mcve]*. There is no need to be ambiguous.

Comment: @IanMiner if you do that you lose information as I have described in previous comments. `[0,0,1]` would be the same as `[1,1,0]`

Comment: @Nick a sorted tuple fo the elements should work

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was working on a solution on that basis, just trying to clarify before posting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like:

```
def cull_faces(all_face_nodes):
    seen = set()
    result = []
    for arr in all_face_nodes:
        key = tuple(sorted(arr.tolist()))
        if key in seen:
            continue
        result.append(arr)
        seen.add(key)
    return result
```

This uses a *set of sorted tuples*. Then, this is just the standard approach to get a list of unique elements from another list, keeping the first of the duplicates that appears.

Comment: Based on the comments and edits, this should be the way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, this was an enormous improvement, and makes much more sense than what I was doing.

Answer (score 2):

How about sorting all those arrays, so that [3,1,2] becomes [1,2,3] and can be easily compared to that?

```
arr = np.sort(all_face_nodes, axis=1)
```

Will produce a (n,3) array

```
uarr = np.unique(axis=0)
```

Will sort those `n` rows  (effectively `np.sort(arr, axis=0)`),  and return only one of the duplicates.

There are only two ways of avoiding the costly comparison of each row to all others, hashing as used by `set` (and `dict`) and sorting as used by `unique`.

Comment: The resulting arrays cannot be resorted, because the handedness of the data points matters. As an intermediary step sorting is fine to build a mask or index list, but the data points have a certain rotational order that matters. There's no guarantee that the order of points in each array is increasing or decreasing. For instance if my point and duplicate are [1,2,3] and [3,1,2], then sorting is fine. But if my point and duplicate are [6, 5, 4] and [5, 4, 6] and I sort them both to compare, then issues will show up downstream. I can guarantee no duplicates will have differing orders.

Comment: `unique` can return the indices of the unique (i.e. first of duplicates), so you recover the original rows (before all sorting)..